# Toast event in Lightning not working

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, toast

Hello I am trying to make a Lightning component common to Community and SF1
. This component has been added as quick action on one of the object detail page.

Now when i am using the toast event, it gives me error as

> Something has gone wrong. [TypeError: Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined] . Please try again.

Code for same -

```
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('state--->1', state);
            if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
                jobApplicantId = response.getReturnValue();
                fromPos = toPos;
                console.log('fileContents.length -->', fileContents.length);
                toPos = Math.min(fileContents.length, fromPos + CHUNK_SIZE);
                console.log('fromPos -->' , fromPos);
                console.log('toPos -->' , toPos);

                if (fromPos < toPos) {
                    this.uploadChunk(component, file, fileContents, fromPos, toPos, attachId);  
                } else if (fromPos == toPos) {
                    //alert('Job Application Successful');
                    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                    console.log('toastEvent -->', toastEvent);
                    toastEvent.setParams({
                        "title": "Success!",
                        "message": "The record has been updated successfully."
                    });
                    toastEvent.fire();
                    component.find("comments").set("v.value", "");
                    component.find("file").getElement().value = "";
                    this.displayJobAppliedButton(component);
                    //component.find("file").getElement().removeAttribute('value');
                }
            } else {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        alert("Error message: " + 
                                 errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }

        });
```

Snapshot - 
[image]
This whole thing is in a helper class? can this be the issue?

Comment: Is this inside SF1 app or community builder?

Comment: I am trying this in SF1

Comment: What type of org it is ?Summer 16 or spring org with locker enabled ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I checked something else. It looks like $A related metehods are not working in SF1 which is working in Community lightning component. Is there any restrcition around that? I tried $A.util.addClass() method and it seems to be failing

Comment: Summer 16 but Locker not enabled

Comment: Are you wrapping your lightning component inside a VF ? Note that if you wrap via VF some of the events won't be avialable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41444/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-kaushik-ray).

Comment: Yes.. I am. Basically I want to create a quick action for a custom object which can only have Vf pages (if I am not wrong). Also is there a list where I can get which components wont be available if I wrap in VF page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description and image ,I see that you are using Lightning components inside the Visualforce page . Having lightning components inside the visualforce ,you will loose certain events as documented in the guide .The events that are not supported are as below

1.force:createRecord

2.force:editRecord

3.force:navigateToList

4.force:navigateToObjectHome

5.force:navigateToRelatedList

6.force:showToast

[Official Documentation On Toast event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_showToast.htm?search_text=toast)

I think you should open an Idea on Idea Exchange to support lightning components directly from publisher actions .