# Suppress error message $A.getCallback() when a Lightning Component is embedded in Visualforce but tries to fire a toast

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-out

I (finally) finished my lightning component to enable & disable a scheduled job for an AppExchange app I'll publish shortly.

I added it to a VF page and all the functionality worked with the exception of toasts, as documented in this response:
[Toast event in Lightning not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128080/toast-event-in-lightning-not-working)

As the toast isn't critical, I'm looking to either have conditional logic in the Lightning Component that only fires a toast if not in VF, or to suppress the error in the Visualforce / Lightning container (I'm not sure which one displays the error).

Thanks!

VF:

```
<apex:page controller="updateUsingLightningCheckboxController">
<apex:includeLightning />
<div id="lightning"/>
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:LightningAdoptionTrackerSetup", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:LightninAdoptionTrackerSetup",
                                   { },
                                   "lightning", 
                                   function(cmp) {
                                       //do some stuff
                                       });
        });
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Example of the toast in my component's helper:

```
    activateApp: function(cmp,evt) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.startScheduler");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            cmp.set("v.isRunButtonDisabled", false);

            toastEvent.setParams({
                "message": response.getReturnValue(),
                "type": "success",
                "duration": 1500
            });
            toastEvent.fire();
        }//if
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your component runs within one/one.app container(i.e in LEX and SF1), all force:xxx event such as `$A.get("e.force:showToast");` would return an Object.

Since the component is inside VF page, the call to `$A.get("e.force:showToast");` would return `undefined`

So all you have to do is have an `if` to check if the event exist or not.

```
//true only if the component runs within one/one.app container
if(toastEvent){
    toastEvent.setParams({
        "message": response.getReturnValue(),
        "type": "success",
        "duration": 1500
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
}
```